# flask check if user selected a file to upload

Tags: python, flask, file-upload

I've checked on stackoverflow and other places and everywhere they use files.filename to check if a file is available or not. If I do this I get the message

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'filename'

Do I miss something? Or is there another way to check if the user has selected a file to upload?

my HTML:

```
  <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload">
    <label>Choose a problem report file (*.zip).
      <input type="file" name="file[]"  multiple="" accept=".zip">
      <input type="submit" value="Upload problem report(s)">
    </label>  
  </form>
```

my python

```
import flask
from werkzeug.wrappers import request
import os
app = flask.Flask("upload")

UPLOAD_FOLDER = './upload'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

def get_html(page_name):
    html_file = open(page_name + ".html")
    content = html_file.read()
    html_file.close()
    return content

@app.route("/upload", methods=["POST"])
def upload():
    files = flask.request.files.getlist("file[]")
    if files.filename !='':
        for file in files:
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file.filename))
    return get_html("index")
```

It's not the best code I know, but if I leave out the check for the filename the upload works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
files = flask.request.files.getlist("file[]")
for file in files:
    if file.filename !='':
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file.filename))
```

As the error message suggested, your get a list, and a list has not `filename` attribute, so you need to check the items in the list.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was indeed the solution! I'm obviously a beginner and you just saved me hours after I already invested hours in this!!
Sadly I don't have enough reputation to mark this answer as usefull, but I'll remember to swing by again once I have enough!